# Which is more important, current or potential difference?

Tags: electric-current, voltage

If i have a bulb rated 4V, 4A, and my power source is 2V, 2A. Should I use a step up or step down transformer to make it 4V, 1A or 1V, 4A? Which wold make it glow brighter?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please use normal English punctuation when asking questions here. For example, Capitalize the first word of each sentence, and capitalize "I". Poorly written questions tend to get less attention by would-be answerers.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I think the concepts needed to answer this are fundamental enough to keep the question here (see my answer, at least the first two paragraphs); and I would expect this question to get a very negative reception on ee.se due to insufficient prior research (on the EE issues).

Comment: OP, please read [this EE question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings) to understand the basics of choosing power supplies.

Answer (score 2):

In electric circuits there is concept called [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(electrical_circuits)), which says that for any phenomenom that occurs related to voltage, there is a *dual* phenomenom related to current. Thus, voltage and current are equally important to understanding electric circuits.

As for your light bulb problem, your light bulb requires 16 W of power to operate. Your supply is only capable of providing 4 W. Therefore your supply is not capable of driving this bulb, whether you use a step up or step down transformer.

Since the bulb equivalent resistance is 1 ohm, and your supply is capable of driving a 1 ohm load, you could try simply connecting your supply to your bulb. However

1. lamps are positive temperature coefficient resistors, so the bulb may actually draw more than 2 A when supplied with 2 V. This could result in overloading your supply.
2. 4 W might not be sufficient to heat the bulb enough to produce visible light.

Comment: I haven't just cribbed and expanded your answer - this was mostly written shortly after it was asked and I saw that you had an answer as I went to post this. We say much the same things but I'm more long winded. No surprise :-).It had occurred to me only after I wrote this that it may be homework and I should maybe not post it but, as the key elements are now well stated I'll add my happorths worth.

Answer (score 0):

Best brightness probably is achieved at 2V - the original setting.
The reasons are more complex than may be apparent at 1st glance.

Neither 1V or 4V is very good and it depends on the characteristics of your light and your power supply. In most case the higher voltage would be better if the only choices were 1V or 4V. This is because the lamp will "load down" the power supply until the load level can be supplied by the supply. But, you cannot "load down" a supply which is already so low that it draws less current than the supply will provide at that voltage.  HOWEVER, by boosting the supply to more than can be supported you reduce the power able to be delivered. And by decreasing the voltage to a level where it cannot deliver as much current as the supply can provide you also reduce the power.

Bulb = 4V, 4A.
Power = V x I = 4 x 4 = 16 Watts

Power available = 2V x 2A = 4W.
This is 25% of what is needed.

Assume the bulb is a linear resistive load - ie a pure resistor.
It will definitely not be but that is a starting point.

Assume that the supply will not provide more than its rated current and that the voltage will decrease as required under overload to keep current from exceeding the maximum value. This is the most typical way a supply would behave.

R lamp = V/I = 4V/$a = 1 Ohm.
On a 4V, 1A supply it will load supply down to 1V as
V = IR = 1A x 1 Ohm = 1 Volt
Power = V x I = 1 x 1 = 1 Watt

On a 1V 4A supply it is already at 1V, so I = V/R = 1V/1 Ohm = 1V - again.
Power = V x I = 1 x 1 = 1 Watt

But if you leave the supply at 2V and 2A max.
I = V/R = 2V/1 Ohm = 2A = supply rating.
Power = V x I = 2V x 2A = 4 Watt.

You get more power into a 1Ohm load by leaving it as was at 2V.

BUT a lamp works differently. When cold it has a very low resistance.
As it heats up its resistaance increases to maybe 10 to 20 x more than when cold.
If there is enough energy available to fully heat it its resistance will be lower than when hot.   So 1 lamp that has one Ohm resistance when hot and 0.05 to 0.1 Ohm when cold will perhaps have 0.25 to 0.5 Ohm resistance when run at 1/4 power.

In this case 0.25 Ohm at 1/2/4 volts draws 4/8/16 A if allowed.
So the 1 V, 4A winding would suit it well.

But 0.5 Ohms at 1/2/4 Volt would draw 2/4/8 A if allowed.
So the 1V winding would deliver 2A and 1V = 2W
The 2V winding would deliver 2A (max allowed) at maybe 2V (if it stayed at 0.5 Ohms) and   maybe 4W or maybe less and
The 4V winding would deliver 1A at 2V  = 2W.
So, again, the 2V winding is probably optimum.

If this was an LED lamp designed to operate from 4V it would perhaps rundimly at 2V and probably not at all at 1V.